# Append to an array in an API node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to append an item to an API in Node.js.

This is my code

```
app.post('/api/scores', function(req, res){
    //creamos el score para guardarlo en la bd
    Score.create({
        userEmail : req.user.email,
        game : game,
        top : top.push(10)
    })
})
```

Can I do this top.push()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if you want to pass the return value of `push`, which is the new length of the array. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Returns).

You probably want

```
top: top.concat(10)
```

because `concat` returns the new array, which is most likely what you want.